# Partition's file system, VFS and root file system

Tags: linux, filesystems

It's clear to me regarding the partition's file system and VFS but not for the root file system.

Let's say I have a disk with 3 partitions which are swap, installation and home. Each partition obviously has its own file system. Then there is VFS which is an interface for the kernel to different file systems (thanks to [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/fs/filesystem.html) because other documents do not mention it).

Now, how the root file system fit together?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My quick perusal suggests that VFS in most cases is transparent to the user, and mainly allows the utility writers to use the same system calls regardless of the actual filesystem format of the partition.

Answer (score 0):

Experts, please verify this.

Based on this [document](http://www.linfo.org/root_filesystem.html), root file system is partition's file system that Linux is installed. The VFS then do the mapping (mount) of other partitions' file system to the root file system.